# How do I iterate over an IndexedDB objectStore using a condition on a non-key property?

Tags: javascript, html, indexeddb

I have a select box that I want to populate automatically with values from a objectStore, for that I need to iterate it like this: "Select COL1 from TABLE where COL2 = 'myvalue'", 
this is my code:

```
var db;
var req = indexedDB.open("DB");
req.onsuccess = function (e) {
    db = req.result;
    var tran = db.transaction("store");         
    var singleKeyRange = IDBKeyRange.only("myvalue"); //the value I want to reach from COL2         
    tran.objectStore("store").openCursor(singleKeyRange).onsuccess = function(e) { 
        var cursor = e.target.result;
        if (cursor) { 
            var opt = document.getElementById("selectbox");
            var option = document.createElement("option");
            var optionText=document.createTextNode(cursor.value.COL1); //the matching values in COL1
            option.appendChild(optionText);
            opt.appendChild(option);
            cursor.continue();
        }
    }
};
```

I have all my values correctly indexed in the objectStore, just don't now how to reach values through others values.

Comment: You will only get one value back because you are filtering on one value. Why do you need to filter? You can get everything from the object store without having to filter...

Comment: In one objectStore I have two "columns", something like; in one there are types of things and in the other there are the names of things, I need to get the names according to a type.

Comment: Try using an index, and open a cursor on that. On my blog http://www.kristofdegrave.be you will find information on how to do it.

Comment: I've tried this also(no success):
var transaction = db.transaction(["store"]); var objstore = transaction.objectStore("store"); var index = objstore.index("myindex"); index.get("myvalue").onsuccess = function(event) { alert("Valores: " + event.target.result.);};

Comment: I was just on your blog, gonna try to figure it out.

Comment: Did you create the index first? And you need to use the openCursor method on the index, not the get. The get will only retrieve 1 record

Comment: tried: var index = objstore.index("myindex"); transaction.objectStore("store").openCursor(index).onsuccess = function(e) { }, says "DataError: Data provided to an operation does not meet requirements".

Comment: using: openCursor(index.value) works but it retrieves the whole "column" and that gets me back to the same, how to get just certain values from it just like in the simple SQL operation above

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is an example in which items are searched on non-indexed column, you need to go through all items and compare the values and add them to list, after that you can return the result set.

```
function SearchItems( keyPath, value, requestNo, callback){
    var initOpenReq = indexedDB.open(baseName);
    initOpenReq.onsuccess = function() {
    var db = initOpenReq.result;
        var transaction = db.transaction(objectStoreName, 'readonly');
        var objectStore = transaction.objectStore(objectStoreName);
        var cursorRequest = objectStore.openCursor();
        var agregate = [];
        cursorRequest.onsuccess = function (event){
            if (event.target.result){
                if(event.target.result.value[keyPath] && event.target.result.value[keyPath] == value){ //compare values
                    agregate.push(event.target.result.value);
                }
                event.target.result['continue']();
            }
        };

        transaction.oncomplete = function (event) {
                callback(agregate); // return items
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Made a lot of changes but this is the way, open an array, store the preliminary objects and then get the desired values from it. Thanks Deni Mf.

Comment: NOTE: the "queries" against a value are case sensitive!

Comment: yes the comparing is case sensitive, but you can the 'toLowerCase' method to compare case insensitive results.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look into it tomorrow.

Comment: This will work, but I would advice you to use an Index, it is going to have a better performance

Answer (score 5):

This is an example with an index.

```
var db; 
var req = indexedDB.open("DB", 2);
// Creating the index
req.onupgradeneeded = function (e){
   var trans = e.target.transaction;
   var obj = trans.objectStore("store");
   obj.createIndex("indexname", "keypath") // keypath is the propertyname you want the index on. for Ex. {Name: "x", Age:5 }; If you want to filter on Name, keypath = Name
} 
req.onsuccess = function (e) {
    db = req.result;
   var tran = db.transaction("store");
   var singleKeyRange = IDBKeyRange.only("myvalue"); //the value I want to reach from COL2              
   var objectStore = tran.objectStore("store");
   var opt = document.getElementById("selectbox");

   objectStore.index("indexname").openCursor(singleKeyRange).onsuccess = 
   function(e){          
         var cursor = e.target.result;
         if (cursor) {
             var option = document.createElement("option");
             var optionText=document.createTextNode(cursor.value.COL1); //the matching values in COL1             
             option.appendChild(optionText);
             opt.appendChild(option);
             cursor.continue(); 
         }
     } 
};
```

Comment: I already add my indexes created so I just extracted the onsuccess() content.
I knew this add to work, makes sense, although I cant help to notice the amount of code for a simple "select" operation.
This leaves now with the problem of case sensitivity for the selection of the indexes.
Once again thanks a lot Kristof.

Comment: yw, for that I would advice you to use a framework. This will take a lot of complexity a way for you.